# Parsing single page application using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, single-page-application

I am working on a simple webapp in JS that parses a website to get some data. The target website I want to parse is a single page web app. When I do a XMLHttpRequest and get the html of the page, its mostly scripts and the elements which I am targeting in the page aren't there. The elements are visible when I access the page from the browser.

I tried injecting the target html into my own page to execute the scripts inside it by doing

```
function tryExecuteJS(targetHtml){
    var flip = document.createElement("div");
    flip.className = 'jfflip';
    flip.style.display = 'none';
    flip.innerHTML=targetHtml;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(flip);
}
```

and tried analysing the source but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the Network tab in chrome dev tools and then xhr to see which URLs your target website is getting and then access those from your script.